# Can Problems Arise When Multiple Servers Use One Mount

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, filesystems, mount

I am using Amazon Web Servers where I have an NFS file system that I mount to several other servers. One mount is shared between about 20 servers and the primary function of the servers is for a web application. While this is nice for now, will solution run into problems such as:

1. Race Conditions
2. High CPU utilization from file locking
3. Other unforeseen problems?

Is there a different way I should be sharing file systems accessed by multiple servers?

Comment: If you tell us why it is shared, whether it's rw or ro, etc. people might have more creative ideas for you. And what type of data is it? Shouldn't your webapp be using a transactional database which would solve those issues?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Race condition**
Yes, there will be race condition on the filer. I.e network bandwidth, disk I/O and etc.

**2. High CPU utilization from file locking.**
There will be high I/O wait if,  application trying to access locked file by another application or NFS lock.

**3. Unforeseen problems.**
Major problem listed above, application with asynchronous I/O will have problem to keep data up to date, however this type of application will use file lock as the mechanism.